# Project Entry point could not located in the dynamic library for my exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, windows-server-2012, armadillo

Firstly, I took a shot with the similar questions in the stackoverflow. But I beleive they are different then mine. Because I couldn't find my answer in those.
Anyway, I developed a C++/CLI project and I used some external libraries in it(armadillo, and npgsql). I developed it in Visual Studio Professional 2012. Program is working on my local computer(I is making all the connections with the Database and read/write processes). The problem is, I am trying to locate my exe file into a Windows Server 2012, and then I am going to run it with another program. So I've tried to copy&Paste my exe file into the server, with all the files in it's location(See below).[This is the file that created when I run the project in "Release" mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I07G9.png)

Anyway, I've tried to run my exe file in the server, and I got an error like below:
[Interesting text in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58UxS.png)

So I've made a little bit search on the internet, but I couldn't find any specific answer to this question(Most of them are about dll's). Can someone help on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your system cannot locate the `std::numpunct` class which is required by this executable. The standard c++ classes are located in a VS DLL, and they are **not** installed  on a computer by default for every visual studio version, so the question: Did you install the visual Studio redistributable on the target host?

If not, please fetch the corresponding package from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003 and install it on the remote computer.